# In first order logic, given F℩xFx, are you able to use alphabetical variation?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am deriving the statement:  ∴ ℩xFx=℩yFy

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDpsE.png)

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I noticed I have F℩xFx and ~F℩yFy

Would I be able to use alphabetical variation to change the x into a y or vice versa to prove the derivation?

Every time I try to use alphabetical variance, it tells me the parser "cannot map  G℩xFx" — I am unsure of what this means.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "℩x" ? Is it ["the unique $x$ such that"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#Mathematical_logic) operator ?

Comment: Intuitively, $℩xFx=℩yFy$ is correct : "the only $x$ such that $F$" is the same object that "the only $y$ such that $F$".

Comment: We have that $℩xFx$ is $\exists x (Fx \land \forall y (Fy \to y=x))$.